# Is it possible to make entities from two different edmx's map to the same class in Entity Framework?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, oracle, entity-framework

I've been asked to make a program I've written work with two different data providers: MS SQL and Oracle.

I've written two separate edmx files: one for the MS SQL database and one for the Oracle SQL database.  Other than the fact that they use different data providers, the schema of the data is exactly the same.

I now have two entity sets and two entity classes.

Since the classes have the same properties, is it possible to use the same .net class for both entity sets?

I got the idea that this may be possible because as the system tried to generate two classes with the same name in different edmx files, it produced an error that said that the properties were defined more than once!

Answer (score 2):

If your database schemas are exactly the same, you can work this out by using one Model with multiple connection strings configured.

To make the code more cleaner, you may inherit two context classes from the one generated for your model:

```
public class MSSQLContext : YourGeneratedContext 
{ 
    public MSSQLContext() 
        : base("MSSQLDatabase") /*MS SQL connection string name in your config file*/
    { 
    } 
}
```

and

```
public class OracleContext : YourGeneratedContext 
{ 
    public OracleContext() 
        : base("OracleDatabase") /*Oracle connection string name in your config file*/
    { 
    } 
}
```

Next, where needed you can create instance of `MSSQLContext` or `OracleContext`, you can work with the two at the same time as well..

```
using(OracleContext mainContext = new OracleContext())
{
    using(MSSQLContext mirrorContext = new MSSQLContext())
    {

    }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592674.aspx

Comment: +1: Interesting answer, but I don't think it's going to work in my particular case.  I think that there must be two different edmx's because they use different providers and two different defining queries... or am I wrong?

Comment: provider is part of entity framework connection string. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716756%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: what do you mean by `defining queries`?

Comment: If schemas are identical then the model (edmx) will be identical. The only difference is the connection string, which can be handled as @Andrew shows by having two contexts. An alternative, and an approach I've used before, is having a single context which takes a string in the constructor for the connection string.

Comment: Yes, different connection string passed to constructor is actually a mechanism, I've based my implementation on. I prefer typed contexts though, the code looks cleaner since you don't have to care about extra parameter to pass...it's always in one place. A matter of personal taste, though ;)

Comment: By "Defining Query", I am referring to the query given in the edmx file that tells how the data is fetched.  Because one is MS SQL and the other is Oracle, the notation is different.

Comment: can you create two different implementations of those in contexts I've defined?